# Does PlayFab Work with Anything Else Other than Unity and Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, playfab

I am developing my own game engine to later (a year from now) develop a game. I am looking into adding multiplayer functionalities in the current phase the engine is right now and am considering azure services and ran into PlayFab. Can my engine communicate with PlayFab or does it have to work with one of their listed engines to use this service?

PlayFab is completely new to me and don't want to go through the hassle of learning it only to be disappointed.

Comment: [PlayFab SDK’s cover Unity, Unreal, C#, Windows, Lua, JavaScript, Cocos2D, ActionScript 3, Android Studio, Objective-C (iOS), Java, NodeJS, Xamarin, and Lumberyard.](https://playfab.com/engineer/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, PlayFab has pre-built SDKs a wide range of languages [(PlayFab supported languages - PlayFab | Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/sdks/languages/), frameworks [(PlayFab supported frameworks - PlayFab | Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/sdks/frameworks/), and scripting languages [(PlayFab supported scripting languages - PlayFab | Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/sdks/scripting/), in addition to Unity and Unreal.

And if you need something else, Azure PlayFab makes out SDK generator freely available for anyone to use, making it simple to roll your own custom SDK [(SDK Generator - PlayFab | Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/sdks/sdkgenerator/).

Comment: Thank you! I was having issues finding the information you just pointed out.